# Filter Shipping Methods Based on chosen region/city from address book

Tags: php, shipping, javascript, html, customer-address

is there any way to filter shipping methods based on customer chosen region/city from address book in checkout process? for example: there are two shipping methods (`A` & `B`). "`A`" is available for all cities and "`B`" is available for just one city. can it be done programmatically or other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a extention need to be created. This link explains the same.. http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-filter-shipping-method-in-onepage-checkout/ and there is one extension (free) where your might get some Idea. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-and-payment-filters.html I hope others might explain more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to filter shipping method in onepage checkout?](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-filter-shipping-method-in-onepage-checkout/)

Create: app/code/local/MagePal/ShippingFilter/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePal_ShippingFilter>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </MagePal_ShippingFilter>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <shipping>
               <rewrite>
                  <shipping>MagePal_Shipmentfilter_Model_Shipping</shipping>
               </rewrite>
           </shipping>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Create: app/code/local/MagePal/ShippingFilter/Model/Shipping.php

```
class MagePal_ShipmentFilter_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
{
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request)) {
            return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    protected function _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request = null)
    {
        $isLoggedIn  = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
        // get login customer address book
        // if customer login and have address on file
        // check payment code
        if(!$isLoggedIn){
            if($carrierCode == ''){ #Hide shipping method
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Create: app/etc/modules/MagePal_ShippingFilter.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
           <modules>
                  <MagePal_ShippingFilter>
                          <active>true</active>
                          <codePool>local</codePool>
                  </MagePal_ShippingFilter>
           </modules>
    </config>
```

Comment: i want a solution to Filter Shipping Methods Based on city; not for payment methods!

Comment: i'm new in magento coding. i will thankful if you explain this with details. what should i do with this codes?

Comment: You will need to create a custom module see http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643 ... then rewrite the shipping model

Comment: thanks. and can you guide me to how to rewrite shipping model in magento?

Comment: Take a look at my update

Comment: Please remember to accept my answer if it solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set allowed carrier codes to the quote (shipping) address with setLimitCarrier method, and then recalculate the shipping rates.